# Jquery update dropdown value on change select and push to URL query

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a sorting filter using **Jquery**. 
when Dropdown value changed it is not updating in URL query string Here is the [link](https://www.icelandadvice.is/v2/iceland-tours/).
When we select Sorting option i.e Lowest Price or any others, it passes values to the URL first time, but when I tried to update Dropdown value again it does not pass value through. here is the code I have so far.

```
jQuery(document).on("change","select",function(){
  jQuery("option[value=" + this.value + "]", this)
  .attr("selected", true).siblings()
  .removeAttr("selected")
});




        /* Get Sorting */
        var _sorting = [];

        jQuery('.sorting option:selected').each(function() {
            //if (jQuery(this).is(".sorting option:selected")) {
                _sorting.push(jQuery(this).val());
            //}
        });





        /* Get data ready */
        var data = {
            'action': 'reload_filtered_list',
            'ss' : _search,
            'sortby': _sorting.join(','),//This part is for join Selected item in URL string.
            'category': _categories.join(','),
            'duration': _durations.join(','),
            'season': _season.join(','),
            'age': _age.join(','),
            'attractions': _attractions.join(','),
            'pickup': _pickup.join(','),

            'pag': 1
        };

        var data_arr = [];
        for (var prop in data) {
            if (prop != 'action') {
                data_arr.push(prop+'='+data[prop]);
            }
        }
        var joined_data = data_arr.join('&');

        _container.html('<div class="job_listing_filtered_loading">Loading...</div>');
        jQuery('.job-filters-container-loading').fadeIn();

        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            _container.html(response);
            jQuery('.job-filters-container-loading').fadeOut();

            window.history.pushState('page2', curr_page_title, curr_page_permalink+'?'+joined_data);
        });

    });

    jQuery('.filter-child input:checked').each(function() {
        var _p = jQuery(this).closest('.child-block');
        _p.show();
    });

});
```

Please Guide me how we can fix this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Thats a big pile of code. Can u reduce it to the relevant parts?

Comment: Someone needs to learn about jQuery's `.map()` method.

Comment: `jQuery(document).on("change","select",function(){
   jQuery("option[value=" + this.value + "]", this)
   .attr("selected", true).siblings()
   .removeAttr("selected")
 });` This part is adding selected attributes to the selected option.

Comment: Hello @Zim84 Here is the explanation of the code https://drive.google.com/file/d/13_u7W9wruCHlxrkP19TaQ1OExouzjMoH/view  Roamer-1888 Can you tell me a bit more in detail so I can implement it to the code.

Comment: you are not picking up the sorting values on change. also, changing the `selected` attribute is done by the browser, you don't need code for that unless you are changing it in multiple dropdowns when a single dropdown selection is changed.